# Load Dropbox files into JList Maven Java NetBeans?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, dropbox-api, jlist

I have created a Maven NetBeans project for Dropbox and I need to call up the files in a folder from Dropox and display them in a JList on the interface.

I am able to print them out in the output using `(System.out.println())` the following:

```
public void GetFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            MainEmpOperations MEMPops = new MainEmpOperations();
            // Get files and folder metadata from Dropbox root directory
            ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolder("/Employees");
            while (true) {
                for (Metadata metadata : result.getEntries()) {
                   System.out.println(metadata.getPathLower());
                }
                if (!result.getHasMore()) {
                    break;
                }
                result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

The coding that I have tried to use for loading the files into the `JList` is similar to the above coding where I will be using `DefaultListModel`.

Here is the coding that I have done so far but it does not list the files in the JList.

```
public void GetFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            MainEmpOperations MEMPops = new MainEmpOperations();
            // Get files and folder metadata from Dropbox root directory
            ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolder("/Employees");
            DefaultListModel modelListFiles = new DefaultListModel();
            while (true) {
                for (Metadata metadata : result.getEntries()) {
                    modelListFiles.addElement(metadata.getPathLower());
                }
                if (!result.getHasMore()) {
                    break;
                }
                result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());                
                MEMPops.List_CloudFiles.setModel(modelListFiles);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Please could someone please help me out, and help me load the files names of the file into the `JList`.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.

The way in which it needs to work is that the adding of the element and the setting of the model will need to be done straight after each other. placing the set model after the if statement results in the model being cleared or it becomes empty.

Therefore the following coding will work for listing of the files in a `JList`.
PLEASE NOTE: the rest of the other coding needed for connection and management from dropbox is on dropbox developers website.

CODING THAT WORKS:

```
    public void GetFiles()
        {
            try
            {
                // Get files and folder metadata from Dropbox root directory
                //please note the employees is a folder that is on dropbox
                ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolder("/Employees");
                DefaultListModel modelListFiles = new DefaultListModel();
                while (true) {
                    for (Metadata metadata : result.getEntries()) {
                        //get name just returns the name of the file and getPathLower() is used for getting the directory and the filename together.
                        modelListFiles.addElement(metadata.getName());
                        List_CloudFiles.setModel(modelListFiles);
                    }
                    if (!result.getHasMore()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());                
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }
```

Like (upvote or mark as helpful) if this answer that I posted to my own question helps you out as well.